# CSS not working in Firefox 2.0

Tags: css, firefox

my site looks right in new browsers, but it won't display the background of the main container in older ones.

here is the css that should put the background there:

```
#container {
background-image:url('photo.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 541px;
width:1020px;
margin: auto;
position: relative;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Where in your folder structure is photo.png in relation to your html file?

Answer (score -1):

am not sure if I am right, but try thiss

`background: url('photo.png') no-repeat;`

Comment: Firefox 2 usually has no problem with specifying them separately.

Comment: maybe firefox 2 did, but I really doubt that

Comment: Why do you doubt a browser that's more standards-compliant than IE7?

Comment: i didn't doubt the browser, just the thought that it might be doubtfull

Answer (score -1):

Try using an absolute path.  You can also ignore Firefox 2.0, which is not used by anyone today.

Comment: so position: relative;
 will be position: absolute; ? What is the difference?

Comment: all the change did was move the container from the middle where it was centered to the left?

Comment: @Matthew24 uh... absolute *path*. `photo.png` is a relative path.  `http://www.example.com/images/photo.png` is an absolute path.

Comment: Okay, I will change that. Is that a problem with firefox 2 and older browsers that you need to specify the whole path for the photo to show?

Comment: @Matthew24: Your code should work in Firefox 2, but I don't see why 1) it doesn't work or 2) it matters to you.